# JqueryUI slider won't show up

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm trying to put a optional slider on my app, I put the jquery slider of jqueryUI but it doesn't work on my web page.

The html is generated via php and the $('#slider').slider() is call in my js

I'll let the code here :

/*CSS*/

```
#slide{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    height: 14px;
    width: 200px;
    top: 35px;
    /*background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.90);*/
    padding : 10px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

/*HTML*/

```
<div id="wrapper" data-role="content">

<div id="slide"><div id="slider"></div></div>

</div>
```

/*JAVASCRIPT */

```
$(document).on("click","#page-slider",function(){
    $('#slide').toggle("slow");
    $('#slider').slider();
});
```

If there's anyone that sees the problem or has an idea, it will be great.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do you have the jQuery UI CSS loaded?  Without it, it will create the slider HTML, but you won't see anything, because there is no CSS for it.

```
<link href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Secondly, why are you initializing the slider in a click function?  You should only have to do this once, on document ready:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#slider').slider();

    $(document).on("click","#page-slider",function(){
        $('#slide').toggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Example without CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/Ehr8y/

Example with CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/Ehr8y/4/

It's the same code, but in the second example, I load the base jquery UI CSS.  If you look at the source of the one without CSS, you will see:

```
<div id="slider" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 0%;"></a>
</div>
```

So, clearly `.slider()` executed.

Comment: I can't initialize the slider() on document ready because the javascript is loaded before the slider element in the html. I realize that initialize it on the click function is not good but I only want to see it one time a fix the other problem after

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  The whole point of `$(document).ready()` is that the script isn't run until all elements are loaded.  If you are doing it correctly, this should work.

Comment: when you call $('#slider').slider(), it produce 
<div id="slider" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
but for me it produce this 

 <div id="slider" class="ui-slider-switch"></div>
 <div class="ui-slider  ui-btn-down-c ui-btn-corner-all" role="application">

Comment: I hate those kind of stupid error. Jquery mobile was suppose to be load only on mobile device, but it wasn't, It was just becasue of this. Thank you for your quick answer

Comment: Sure.  Click the check mark next to my answer please.  Accepting answers makes sure that people will answer your questions in the future.